# Is std::atomic thread-safe for reading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

My purpose -- only one thread can process data at the same time. I have used std::mutex, std::unique_lock, `try_lock` it works pretty well.

But someone argued, why not just use atomic variable? Something like this,

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

std::atomic_bool isRunning = false;

void process() {    
    if (isRunning)
    {
        return;
    }
    isRunning = true;
    cout << "processing ..." << endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    cout << "finished" << endl;
    isRunning = false;
}

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    std::thread th1(process);
    std::thread th2(process);
    std::thread th3(process);
    std::thread th4(process);
    std::thread th5(process);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    th3.join();
    th4.join();
    th5.join();
}
```

By my experience, atomic is safe for writing, but not safe for reading. For example, `if (isRunning)`, maybe 2 threads get the same `false` value at the same and both run into the processing code.

But I tested several times, no such case, all just show one message

> processing ...

I didn't find any document about it, how do you think about it?

Comment: Fetching or setting the value of an atomic is atomic and can't be preempted by other threads. *But* once the value is fetched (or written) using the value is not atomic. Take for example `if (isRunning)` from your code: The fetching of the boolean value is atomic and thread safe, but using the value in the comparison can be preempted. Which means one thread can fetch the value, another thread set it to true, and the first thread use the old false value.

Comment: I think you're looking for [compare_exchange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The posted code is thread-safe in the sense that it won't invoke undefined behavior, but not-thread-safe in the sense that it isn't going to give you the behavior you are trying to guarantee.

In particular, there is a race condition in this code:

```
if (isRunning)
{
    return;
}
// XXX
isRunning = true;
```

Imagine the scenario where thread A executes, and gets as far as the line where the XXX comment is shown above... then the OS's scheduler preempts thread A and allows thread B to execute, and thread B sets `isRunning` to `true` and starts doing its usual processing.  Then thread A gets back onto the CPU, sets `isRunning` to `true` (again), and also starts doing its processing.

At that point, you have both thread A and thread B processing data at the same time, which is what you were trying to avoid.

The upshot is:  for this purpose, a mutex is the right tool for the job; an atomic variable has its uses, but it won't let you (efficiently) block one thread's progress until another thread has finished executing a critical section, and that is the behavior that you want in this program.

Comment: @wohlstad: I'm not convinced that *is* a data race, because the data type is atomic. An atomic read followed by an atomic write is not a data race in the context of the ISO standard. The program may well misbehave but that's no different than a banking app withdrawing $20 from your account and depositing $50 into mine :-) It's a program logic error rather than a language constraint violation.

Comment: @paxdiablo I stand corrected. The mention of "race condition" automatically led me to associate it with UB. Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 4):

`mutex` is the tool designed for this job, so if you are already using it, there is no reason to use `atomic` instead. Depending on the implementation, `mutex` can be more efficient or wake up faster.

That being said, you can use `atomic` as a lock, but it is not enough to use `isRunning = true` because multiple threads can get past `if (isRunning)` before you set the value. Instead, you should use [compare_exchange_weak](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) to compare and set in atomic manner:

```
// Before the critical section
bool expected;
do {
    expected = false;
} while (!isRunning.compare_exchange_weak(expected, true));

// Critical section here
    
// Unlock at the end
isRunning = false;
```

This will consume a lot of CPU time because it is constantly checking the value. You can add a counter to give time for other threads in case the wait takes a long time:

```
bool expected;
size_t counter = 0;
do {
    expected = false;
    if (counter > 100) {
        Sleep(10);
    }
    else if (counter > 20) {
        Sleep(5);
    }
    else if (counter > 3) {
        Sleep(1);
    }
    counter++;
} while (!isRunning.compare_exchange_weak(expected, true));
```

Comment: You might want to emphasize that the implementation shown in this answer is a *spinlock* and as such will only be efficient in the case where no thread ever remains within the critical section for any significant amount of time.  In programs where the critical section takes any significant amount of time (e.g. doing I/O or extended calculations), you'd end up with all of the other threads pinning each pinning a core at 100% the entire time, which would be ungood.

Comment: Moreover, efficient spinlocks do not spin or (compare-)exchange, since it involves cache contention. They spin on read instead. (Plus also care about memory ordering.)

Answer (score 3):

Atomics *are* safe for the operation they have atomicity over (by definition). So. for example, you're guaranteed that nothing will change the atomic *while you're reading it.*

However, *your* code needs the entire read/check/write sequence to be atomic, which is *not* guaranteed in this case.

You either need to use something that can make the whole sequence atomic (like a mutex), or rely on something like an atomic compare-and-swap.

Just be aware that, if your code is going to loop until the compare-and-swap works, there's not really a lot of difference between that and a mutex. In fact, a mutex *may* even be preferable since it can put threads to sleep until the mutex is released, rather than spinning them all while waiting for the resource to become free.